# Derivative $\partial f$ of $f(z) = \mathrm{dist}(z,B(a,r))$ where $B(a,r)$ is a ball in $\mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

Let $B(a,r)$ be a (closed) ball or radius $r>0$ centered at $a \in \mathbb C$. Further, let $f$ be given by
$$
f(z) = \mathrm{dist}(z,B(a,r))
$$
where $\mathrm{dist}(z,B(a,r))$ denotes the Euclidean distance of $z$ to the ball $B(a,r)$.
If want to calculdate $\partial f$ where $\partial = \frac12( \partial_x - i \partial_y)$ outside of the boundary of the ball (where $f$ is not differentiable).

So far I'm failing to calculate $\partial f$. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If $a = 0$, and $r = 1$, then $f(z) = |z-\frac{z}{|z|}|$. Surely you can compute the derivatives of this function. To get the result for $B(a,r)$, compose $f$ with an affine transformation which sends $B(a,r)$ to $B(0,1)$, and use the chain rule.